# How do I know if there is a number in my list?

Tags: regex, perl, if-statement, numbers, int

My code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$counter=0;
@list=<STDIN>;
chomp(@list);
if (@list==~ /^[+-]?\d+$/ )
{
$counter++;
}
print $counter;
```

So I write datas like: *a b c d 1 2*
And then it should print `2`

beacuse of the *1,2*

But it does not matter what datas i write into the list i get back `0`.
So what is the problem with my `if`?

Comment: See also [`Scalar::Util::looks_like_number`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util#looks_like_number) and `$RE{num}` in [`Regexp::Common`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Always* `use strict; use warnings;`. If your goal is to count the number of digit elements in your list, you can use `grep` to filter the list elements, then apply `scalar` to get its length (or use `$length` directly instead of storing the filtered list in `@matches`):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @list = <STDIN>;
chomp(@list);
my @matches = grep /^[+-]?\d+$/, @list;
print scalar @matches . "\n";
```

Sample run:

```
$ ./count.pl
-62
a
b
4
c
+91023
d
3
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!
One more question for you:
How do I know if there is a number in a sentence?
for example: I am 2 years old.
and then it would print ' "1" ' .

Comment: @MTn: If you have a new question, then please put it in a new post (but stop and have a think about it first!)

Comment: Yes, new questions should be in their own thread, but just `$sentence =~ /\d+/;` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it looks like you just guessed at this syntax. That's not really a great way to write a program :-)

Your main problems are on this line:

```
if (@list==~ /^[+-]?\d+$/ )
```

There are two pretty big problems here. Firstly, the `@list`. The match operator (`=~`) works on a single string at a time. So you need to use it on a scalar value. And if you give it an array (as you have done here) then Perl will (silently) evaluate the array as a scalar - which means that rather than getting the contents of the array, you'll get the number of elements in the array - which will be an integer so your regex will always match.

But, you say, it doesn't match. Yes, I realise that. And that's down to your second error - you have the match operator wrong. The operator is `=~` and you're using `==~` (see the extra `=`). You would hope that an error like that cause a syntax error, but you've accidentally used a version that is syntactically valid but just doesn't do what you want. Perl interprets your code as:

```
if (@list = =~ /^[+-]?\d+$/ )
```

Note the spaces I've added. The one between the two `=` characters is important. This is saying "perform the match operation and assign the results to `@list`". But what is the match operator matching against? Well, it hasn't been given an explicit variable to match against, and in that case it matches against the default variable, `$_`. You haven't put anything into `$_` so the match fails.

At this point, I should point out that if you had `use warnings` in your code, then you would be getting all sorts of useful warnings about what you're doing wrong. All Perl programmers (including the most experienced ones) should always have `use strict` and `use warnings` in their code.

There's another point of confusion here. It's the way you read your input.

```
@list = <STDIN>;
```

You haven't made it clear, but I suspect that you type in your list all in one line. In that case, you don't want to store your input in an array; you should store it in a scalar.

```
chomp($list = <STDIN>);
```

You can then convert it to a list (to be stored in an array) using `split()`.

```
@list = split /\s+/, $list;
```

You can then get the count of numbers in your array using `grep`.

```
my $count = grep { /^[-+]\d+$/ } @list;
```

When evaluated as a scalar, `grep` returns the number of times the block of code was true.

Putting those together (and adding `strict` and `warnings`) we get the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

chomp(my $list = <STDIN>);

my $count = grep { /^[-+]\d+$/ } split /\s+/, $list;
```

Which, to my mind at least, looks simpler than your version.